Is there a systematic rule to determine how the regions (to be treated separately) should be split when solving Laplace equations?
Is there a systematic rule to determine how the regions (to be treated seperatly) should be split when solving lapalce equations? For example when finding potential near a conducting sphere or a charged ring, it's okay to consider only the inner and outer region of the conductor ($r>R$ and $r<R$). But for case like conducting plate, I'm pretty sure $r>R,r<R$ is not enough. So is there any kind of rule for this?

You need to be more precise.  What is R?  What does "inner outer region" even mean?

If the radius of a ring is R, then the inner region is space defined by rR when using spherical coordinates. For a sphere, the inner region is space inside the sphere and the outer region is the space outside the sphere. When solving Laplace equations we assign different forms of potentials depending on whether the region includes the origin(inside: $\sum A_l r^l P_l(\cos \theta)$ outside:$\sum B_l r^(-l-1)P_l(\cos \theta)$)However, for conducting plate, these are not enough and you have four regions to treat seperately.

So the question is what is the criteria for splitting the regions?

You first choose your coordinate system so that you have discontinuities at surfaces where one coordinate is a constant.  For your example of a charged ring, that could be either spherical or cylindrical coordinates.  You then need to have a split at every discontinuity, so that each region is homogeneous.  For your plate, that means you need a split at theta = 0 (or z = 0 for cylindrical coordinates) as well as at r = R.  That's the main criterion: after splitting, each region is homogeneous.
When you have multiple choices, like between using cylindrical or spherical coordinates above, one choice will often be better, in that the sums you mention will converge more quickly.
